# How to add and remove ng-bind from elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am working on a Drag&Drop Dashboard, part of it is written with **AngularJS**.

I am using a select for my Dropdown-Menu:

```
<select ng-model="selected_option" ng-options="object.id for object in options"></select
```

When i select an option, i show a list of related elements:

```
<li ng-repeat="option in selected_option.columns"><div class="alert alert-success">{{option.header}}</div></li>
```

So, when i Drag&Drop the list-element to my "board" (inside given divs), and change the selected option again, all related elements are gone.

This is working as it should, of course.

> But how to prevent the removing of my elements which are "draged" to
>   the board?

**Summarize:**

- I have a list of elements via ng-repeat on the left.
- I drag them to the right side (to my board). I wanted them to stay
  there, even if i change the select.
- If i drag them again to the list on the list, they should be gone
  when i reselect the dropdown.

EDIT: A small [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/4482/)

Or would it be nicer to do everything with jQuery? I love the 2-Way-Data-Manipulation from Angular, but if this ng-bind removing is too much work, i could also do it with jQuery.

Comment: Do you have any script you can show?   I mean, i usually do this stuff in jQ, not angular, but thats because im more familiar with 1 over the other

Comment: Any chance of a JSFiddle?

Comment: I updated my post with a JSFiddle

Comment: Thanks. When you say "removing of my elements which are dragged to the board", what exactly do you mean? Removed from where? Their original starting position?

Comment: Drag the text-elements to the right side after select one id. Then, change the id inside with the dropdown > The text-elements are gone from the right side. I want them to stay there. I'm thinking of changing the scope, but i don't know what a proper solution would be...